# After changing sa password I'm (sometimes) getting a Timeout exception

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I've changed the sa password in SQL server which used to be the same as the administrator password of the system. After that, I'm getting this error sometimes:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at
```

I'm running windows server 2008 R2 and SQL Server Enterprise.

Do you have any clue on how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you still connect to the instance using Management Studio? When you do, are you connecting as sa or as your Windows account?

Comment: Yes, I can connect to the Management Studio using windows authenticatoin and sql server authentication. I have rebooted after the change, and it's still causing me problems :(

Answer (score 1):

It’s highly unlikely that changing SA password can cause this kind of problems.

I’d suggest you try following:

- Try different account and see what happens – it’s much better practice not to use SA account for applications anyway.
- Check out your application settings – maybe you’ve set connection timeout to some low value
- Check error logs for sql server in event viewer – there are probably more details there that can help you with this…

Comment: I've found this on the event viewer, this is the only "weird" message from sql server that I can find: Autogrow of file 'mjtravelshop_log' in database 'mjtravelshop' was cancelled by user or timed out after 30155 milliseconds.  Use ALTER DATABASE to set a smaller FILEGROWTH value for this file or to explicitly set a new file size.